# Getting error on Angular website 'Cannot read property of undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**I am getting an error when trying to navigate to drawings/:id. The error states "Cannot read property of undefined." I am trying to show details on a drawing when I click on the drawing and it should take an id from my json file to route to the page.

It seems like the error is occurring somewhere in the getDrawing(id: number) function or in my drawingService service. Is there anything someone can see I may be missing?

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DrawingListComponent } from './drawings/drawing-list.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { FavoriteDrawingsComponent } from './favorite-drawings/favorite-drawings.component';
import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts/contacts.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './user/login.component';
import { DrawingDetailsComponent } from './drawings/drawing-details/drawing-details.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DrawingListComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FavoriteDrawingsComponent,
    ContactsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DrawingDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'drawings', component: DrawingListComponent}, 
      {path: 'drawings/:id', component: DrawingDetailsComponent},      
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},      
      {path: '*', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { DrawingService } from '../drawing.service'
import { IDrawing } from '../drawing';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './drawing-details.component.html'
})
export class DrawingDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    drawing: IDrawing | undefined;   
    errorMessage: string = '';

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private drawingService: DrawingService,
                private router: Router){ }
                
    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        //this.drawingId = id;
        this.getDrawing(id);
       
    }
    getDrawing(id: number) {
        this.drawingService.getDrawing(id).subscribe(drawing => this.drawing = drawing,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img *ngIf = "drawing" [src] = "drawing.imageUrl">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ drawing.name }}            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ drawing.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ drawing.imageUrl }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:500px">
<div class='container col-10'>
  
  <header class="">
    
  </header>
  
  <div class="container">
      <table class='table'>{{ favList }}
        </table>
  <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class='table'>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor = "let drawing of drawings">
      <td>{{ drawing.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ drawing.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ drawing.description }}</td>
      <td><a [routerLink] = "['/drawings', drawing.id]">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail float-right pic" [src] = "drawing.imageUrl" >
      </a></td>
      <td><button (click) = "onClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Favorite</button></td>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-favorite-drawings *ngIf="isFav" #favDrawings (addFavorite) = "favAdded($event)" [myFav] = "drawing.name" [favId] = "drawing.id" ></app-favorite-drawings>
     </tr>
  </table>
  
  </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IDrawing } from './drawing';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable ({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DrawingService {
    private productAPI = 'assets/drawings.json';

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
    }
    
    getDrawings(): Observable<IDrawing[]> {
        return this.http.get<IDrawing[]>(this.productAPI);       
    }
   getDrawing(id: number): Observable<IDrawing | undefined> {
        return this.getDrawings().pipe(
            map((drawings: IDrawing[]) => drawings.find(d => d.id === id)));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi David, can you please not put code in a snippet that doesn't run/ doesn't show the error you're getting as it makes it very hard to read. There is formatting to show that a bit of text is code, it's better to use that with some titles saying `xyz.ts`

Comment: Search [so] for the error message: https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+Cannot+read+property+of+undefined+site:stackoverflow.com. If you want more help you will need to include **all** the error details, open the browsers development console and copy/paste *but* read it first, you can probably figure it out by yourself if you do.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info very much, George. I'm new to the site obviously. The error actually doesn't show into I build and run the site then try to navigate to the webpage.

Comment: Drawing Details Component has got a typo. 

 ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); //**REMOVE THE '+' 
        //this.drawingId = id;
        this.getDrawing(id);
       
    }.
Please post a screenshot of the error on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow I figured out the issue and it was such a novice mistake.. So the code was fine. The issue was the JSON file. In the sample JSON file I'm getting my data from I had:

{ "id": "1",
  "name": "Kid's Chemistry",
  "description": "Girl doing chemistry with dad.",
  "imageUrl": "http://www.drawnworks.com/images/Tale of Two Books/GirlChemistry.jpg"
}

But my methods were looking for id as a number so I just had to simply remove the quotes for the id property on each of the drawing objects in the JSON file:

{ "id": 1,
  "name": "Kid's Chemistry",
  "description": "Girl doing chemistry with dad.",
  "imageUrl": "http://www.drawnworks.com/images/Tale of Two Books/GirlChemistry.jpg"
}

Now the pages load fine since the methods are receiving a number type parameter. Thanks Igor and DEVCNN for such quick responses on this post this morning. Sorry for any issues in the post and any details I was missing in this somewhat rushed post. I was going to add the JSON file to the post, and that's when I noticed the problem.. Thanks guys!